# FastAPI RedirectResponse custom headers

Tags: python, redirect, authorization, fastapi

Based off of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279710), I need to now add a header to the response.

According to [the documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-headers/), I can simply just add the headers and another attribute to the `RedirectResponse` object.

When I test this, it doesn't seem to carry the header value over.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583461/redirect-to-page-and-send-custom-http-headers/41218304#41218304), it is impossible to set headers for a redirect request. So instead of a Redirect, maybe I should try something else?

Any ideas?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/data/")
async def api_data(request: Request):
    params = str(request.query_params)
    url = f'http://some.other.api/{params}'
    headers = {'Authorization': "some_long_key"}
    response = RedirectResponse(url=url, headers=headers)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to do the request in the app and then return the response

**BUT** this is **very inefficient** and will force all traffic to come through this server, while a redirect would have less network load

```
import requests
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/data/")
async def api_data(request: Request):
    params = str(request.query_params)
    url = f'http://some.other.api/{params}'
    headers = {'Authorization': "some_long_key"}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return Response(content=r.content)
```