# proxy an external website using python fast api not supporting query params

Tags: python, fastapi, httpx

I am trying to proxy an external website (Flower monitoring URL running on different container) using python Fast API framework:

```
client = AsyncClient(base_url=f'http://containername:7800/monitor')

@app.get(“/monitor/{path:path}”)
async def tile_request(path: str):
    req = client.build_request("GET", path)
    r = await client.send(req, stream=True)
    return StreamingResponse(
        r.aiter_raw(),
        background=BackgroundTask(r.aclose),
        headers=r.headers
   )
```

It is able to proxy the container URL for every path. For ex.

http://python_server:8001/monitor/dashboard --> http://containername:7800/monitor/dashboard

http://python_server:8001/monitor/tasks --> http://containername:7800/monitor/tasks

It works well. But it fails when the PATH has some query params in the URL.

For ex.

```
http://python_server:8001/monitor/dashboard?json=1&_=1641485992460 --> redirects to http://containername:7800/monitor/dashboard
```

**(Please note that no query params are appended to the URL).**

Can anyone please help with how we can proxy this external website's any path with any query param.

Comment: you only pass the path, you dont capture or pass the query params. you can get them from the request object,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI variable query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279710/fastapi-variable-query-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, I think it should work.. need to check how i can pass the query param to httpx client.

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73770074/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73672334/17865804)

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me and is used in production:

```
import httpx
from httpx import AsyncClient
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask

app = FastAPI()
HTTP_SERVER = AsyncClient(base_url="http://localhost:8000/")

async def _reverse_proxy(request: Request):
    url = httpx.URL(path=request.url.path, query=request.url.query.encode("utf-8"))
    rp_req = HTTP_SERVER.build_request(
        request.method, url, headers=request.headers.raw, content=await request.body()
    )
    rp_resp = await HTTP_SERVER.send(rp_req, stream=True)
    return StreamingResponse(
        rp_resp.aiter_raw(),
        status_code=rp_resp.status_code,
        headers=rp_resp.headers,
        background=BackgroundTask(rp_resp.aclose),
    )

app.add_route("/{path:path}", _reverse_proxy, ["GET", "POST"])
```